# Number of submodules of a group algebra for a nonabelian finite group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory, modules, representation-theory

> Let $G$ be a finite, **non**abelian group and suppose we have the group algebra $\mathbb CG$, where $\mathbb C$ is the complex field.  How can I prove that there are infinitely many submodules?

I know that if $G$ isn't abelian then there’s at least one component that its a matrix with dimension at least $2$,  but I don't know how to finish, I’ll be thankful if someone helped me

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Are you looking for $\mathbb{C}$-submodules of $\mathbb{C}G$?

Comment: Thank you! I'm trying to prove that the number of the submodules of CG is infinite if G is an non-abelian group @HallaSurvivor

Comment: Right, but over what ring? $\mathbb{C}$-submodules are just $\mathbb{C}$ vector spaces. So as a $\mathbb{C}$-module, $\mathbb{C}G \cong \mathbb{C}^{|G|}$. Of course, since nonabelian groups have size at least $6$, there are _lots_ of submodules, but it doesn't sound like we're proving anything (and we aren't really using the nonabelian hypothesis). But as a module over itself, there might _also_ be infinitely many submodules. The proof will be more involved, though.

Comment: I don't have  a specific field, the data is - G is non-abelian and finite group and we have the regular module (with complex field) and that's it. so I want to prove what I wrote in the post. @HallaSurvivor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "ideal", I mean a left ideal. I write elements of $\mathbb C^n$ as column vectors.

Since $\mathbb C$ has characteristic $0$, there exist $r_1, \ldots, r_k\in\mathbb N$ (corresponding to irreducible representations of $G$) such that:
$$\mathbb C[G]\cong\prod_{i=1}^k M_{r_i}(\mathbb C)$$
Since $G$ is non-abelian, $\mathbb C[G]$ is non-commutative. Therefore, the $r_i$ cannot all be $1$. WLOG, $r_1\ge 2$.
It suffices to show that $M_{r_1}(\mathbb C)$ has infinitely many ideals. For any $z\in\mathbb C$, define the following ideal of $M_{r_1}(\mathbb C)$:
$$E_z:=\left\{\left.\begin{pmatrix}
v & z v & 0 & \cdots & 0
\end{pmatrix}\right|v\in\mathbb C^{r_1}\right\}$$
Then $\{E_z|z\in\mathbb C\}$ is an infinite family of ideals of $M_{r_1}(\mathbb C)$.

Comment: Thanks! can you show me anther proof without using ideals, because I didn't learn it. @jb78685

Comment: @Ronal12  You're free to replace "ideal of a ring" with "submodule of a ring with respect to itself". It means the same thing.

Comment: Thank you! @jb78685

Comment: I'm not sure I can understand what $E_z$ contains. Do you mean matrices with the first column $v$, second column $zv$, and all the other columns are zero?

Comment: @user26857 Yes.